# Quickest way to iterate through django database records and store in python dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dictionary, django-models

I am using Django ORM to query two models, each model return huge amount of data( 1500 records/model) and then I iterate through the records and store it in the python dictionary. This takes a very long time for the view to execute and as a result the user is just waiting for the page to load while all this processing happens in the views. Is there any way by which I could make this process fast?

```
meter = ostk_vm_tenant_quota_stats.objects.filter(cluster=site, collected_at=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
records = []
for record in meter:
    record_dict = {}
    record_dict['cluster'] = record.cluster
    record_dict['tenant'] = record.tenant
    record_dict['instances_limit'] = record.instances_limit
    record_dict['instances_used'] = record.instances_used
    record_dict['vcpu_limit'] = record.vcpu_limit
    record_dict['vcpu_used'] = record.vcpu_used
    record_dict['memory_limit'] = record.memory_limit
    record_dict['memory_used'] = record.memory_used
    record_dict['disk_limit'] = record.disk_limit
    record_dict['disk_used'] = record.disk_used
    records.append(record_dict)
return render_to_response('tabs1.html', {'data': records})
```

I do the same thing for other model.  "meter" has huge amount of records which I am iterating through to store in the dictionary. Can I make this process faster?

Comment: 1500 isn't really huge. Are you sure this is the slow part?

Comment: I don't think so querying the models is time consuming, it's  iterating through all the records and storing in the dictionary that is taking a very long time

Comment: Any chance `record.cluster` or `record.tenant` are foreignkey relations?

Comment: @kalhartt: record.cluster is the foreign key of model "cluster"

Answer (score 2):

Since (as you mentioned in the comments) `record.cluster` is a foreign key, every time you access it django is performing another db lookup. This means you are hitting the db for every iteration of the loop. Check the docs on [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for a more info.

You can either use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to prefetch the related clusters, or use `record.cluster_id` if you only need the primary key value.

```
# using select related
meter = ostk_vm_tenant_quota_stats.objects \
                                  .select_related('cluster') \
                                  .filter(cluster=site, collected_at=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

# or only use the pk value in the result dict
record_dict['cluster'] = record.cluster_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
meter = ostk_vm_tenant_quota_stats.objects.filter(cluster=site,
            collected_at=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")).values()
```

will give you a ValueQuerySet, which is basically a Python list of dictionaries.  Each dictionary will be all of the fields for each item that matches your query; basically exactly the same as what you have above.